# Remove outline only on click event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to remove the focusable HTML tags' outline only when focus is triggered by a `click` event. This means I would like to keep outline for tabbing.

Does anyone know a practice or library I could use here?

If not, my idea is attaching an `event listener` to `window` that listens to `click` events and is nullifying target style outline on focus in the global styled component.

Is that a viable solution?

(Using React)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a library or JavaScript to do this. CSS has you covered.
Use the [`focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) pseudo selector to help you out.

```css
*:focus-visible {
    outline: 3px dashed rebeccapurple;
    outline-offset: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me to see no focus but tab to me and you will see my focus</button>
<br>
<button>Click me to see no focus but tab to me and you will see my focus</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that straight works in the server-side generated GlobalStyles.
PS: No you can't use my solution with the event listeners. The style is collected and sealed on Nextjs server before handing to client. Felt it but worth a try ...